# Map multiple drives to the same directory for samba/smb clients

Tags: hard-drive, samba

I am trying to solve this specific problem:

1) I want to figure out some way to combine the capacities of multiple physical HDD's into what appears to be a single directory *as seen by windows clients over smb shares*.

I am looking for a solution where the files on different drives can appear to be in the same directory on the filesystem.  In other words, I do not want drive D mounted to C:\files\otherdrive where I might run out of space if I move files between C:\files\otherdrive and anywhere else on drive C.

2) I want a drive failure to mean losing only some files, and I can resume using the remaining drives without spending hours running a recovery program.

I am looking for some solution where if all files are roughly the same size, and one drive out of 3 dies, I lose 33% of my files and get on with my life without having to initiate a 16-hour recovery process with a recovery program that may or may not accomplish anything.

It seems that specific information about this type of event is rare, I have not found any JBOD-like solution where the recoverability of ALL the data isn't in question as the result of a failure of a single drive.  Most advice is no more specific than 'you should assume you lose 100% of data if a drive fails in hardware or software JBOD'

To reiterate, these files are not critical, I don't care if *a reasonable portion* of my files get lost if a drive dies, I just don't want to lose everything and need to spend many hours recovering.  For these reasons, Raid-0 seems out of the question and the implementations of JBOD I have read about seem unusuable or mostly unsatisfactory (you can get some files back by manually running a recovery program on each drive).

Do any solutions exist that meet these requirements?  So far I have only been able to find solutions that satisfy one requirement or the other.

Solutions requiring directory structure awkwardness:
Mount one drive as a subdirectory of another drive

Solutions where all data is gone if one drive fails:
Raid-0, All flavors of JBOD that I researched

I am open to using other operating systems and even buying reasonably-priced consumer level hardware.

Thanks very much for all advice

Edit:  I'm very familiar with raid 0, 1, 0+1, and 5.  I don't -think- raid is what I want because

a) the data is not valuable enough to have any redundancy.  As I stated above, if a drive that represents 45% of the total capacity dies, I -want- to lose roughly 45% of my data.

b) I plan to use drives of different sizes

c) I would like some freedom to add/remove physical drives without severe consequences to all the data (see point A, dead drive counts as a removal in some cases...)

Thanks again

Comment: How many HDDs are you wanting to combine? RAID solution seems to be what you're after. RAID will make several HDD appears as if it is 1 massive HDD (or a single directory). RAID0 = any drive fail = full data loss. RAID5 (minimum 4 HDD) means if you lose 1 HDD, your data is still intact, but you need to replace that broken HDD as soon as possible before a full data loss happening (or more HDD dying).

Comment: Useful reading: [http://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them](http://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them).

Comment: @Darius [Don't use RAID 5](https://www.google.com/search?q=don't+use+raid+5) -- if two disks die, so does the array, and the parity stripe means you pay extra for every write. These days it's trivial to achieve both better performance and better resilience, as for example by the method I detail in my answer, below.

Comment: @AaronMiller Noted. Thank you for the feedback. Something new I learn.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you want both to be able to combine multiple physical disks into a single logical volume, and to have some redundancy such that a single disk failure doesn't cost you your entire filesystem.

Assuming I've read you correctly, your optimal solution would appear to be what's commonly called "RAID 10" or "RAID 1+0" -- that is, two or more RAID 1 (mirrored) volumes, combined into a single RAID 0 (striped) volume.

This way, you get the benefits of both RAID levels, without the drawbacks of either -- RAID 0 has no resilience, in that a single disk failure destroys the whole array, but in a RAID 10 scheme you overcome that by striping over logical volumes composed of multiple physical disks. This way, as long as there's at least one surviving member of each RAID 1 volume, you don't lose data.

Of course, if an entire RAID 1 volume *does* fail, then you lose everything, just as with any other RAID 0 volume, so you're not entirely without risk; that said, if you can afford a half-dozen disks and build your RAID 1 volumes with three each, you get an array which can withstand two disk failures in the worst case, and four in the best, before it fails on you. (None of which is any excuse for not keeping backups!)

Wikipedia offers [a decent high-level overview of RAID 10 as well as other combinations of RAID levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_RAID_levels#RAID_1.2B0), and every major OS these days offers software RAID, so you shouldn't need all that smart a disk controller in order to implement two-level nesting such as RAID 10 -- if your motherboard or PCIe SATA controller can do RAID 1, you can create the mirrored arrays in hardware and use your OS's software RAID to stripe across them, and you're good to go from there.

Comment: Since you're suggesting RAID-10 which requires four disks, why not also suggest RAID 6, under which *any* two disks can fail.

Comment: @paddy Because under RAID 6, *at most* two disks can fail, while a six-disk RAID-10, such as the one I talk about in my answer, can survive *at least* two failures, and at most twice that many. Even assuming a four-disk RAID-1, RAID-6 still loses on write performance -- it's actually worse than RAID-5 in that regard, due to the extra parity stripe -- and also on available space, because the parity stripes eat up space which a RAID-10 would expose to the user.